# Pepper: People ID

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I want to learn face, track it and delete from the database. So I send a string, lets say `'temp'` to the Learn Face block and after success I send the same `'temp'` string to the `peopleID` of the People Tracker block. But I'm getting either:

```
ALTracker.GenericTracker :registerTarget:0  
_ALTargetManager::addTarget         
_PeopleConverter::setImplParam  
ALMotion: ALTracker.PeopleConverterImplParamsInfos ALValue is not an array.
```

error or the robot does not track only the face, but can stare on the head-shaped part of pepper's box, even though he's supposed to track the face he has remembered. Should I use another `peopleID`? Maybe `peopleID` is a number?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your connections?

Comment: yes, here it is https://imgur.com/a/O004mKs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right. PeopleID is a number. But the problem is that you might not track the person you have just learned the face, because there is no association between faceID and peopleId (as far as I know), i.e., Pepper doesn't know 'temp' belongs to which peopleId. You might encounter this problem when several person are standing in front of Pepper and you want Pepper tracks 'temp'.

Comment: As cactie says, there is no relation between peopleID and faceID.
You cannot track a person, only the face.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's pretty strange: to track the only person I need always check his face then.